# Instantiate object of a class before main() executes

Tags: c++

Is it possible to instantiate an object of a class even before main() executes?  If yes, how do I do so?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Global objects are created before `main()` gets called.

```
struct ABC {

   ABC () {
      std::cout << "In the constructor\n";
   }
};

ABC s;  // calls the constructor

int main()
{

   std::cout << "I am in main now\n";
}
```

Comment: How does this work?  Doesn't the execution start at main()? Can you throw some light?

Comment: @Shree: No. Global (and a few other) variables have to be created before `main()`, because they are required to be usable when `main()` starts. So their constructors have to be called before `main()`.

Comment: Is this guaranteed: "It is implementation-defined whether the dynamic initialization of a non-local variable with static storage duration is done before the first statement of main. If the initialization is deferred to some point in time after the first statement of main, it shall occur before the first use of any function or variable defined in the same translation unit as the variable to be initialized. Also refer 3.6.2/3 which to me looks like can also take over and 's' constructor may not even be called

Comment: @Chubsdad: you're right for globals defined in a different TU than `main` itself - their initialization might be deferred. But in Prasoon's example, of course `s` must be initialized "before the first use of any function or variable defined in the same translation unit", and hence before `main` is entered.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can do it like so:

```
#include <iostream>

struct X {
    X() { std::cout << "X()\n"; }
};

X x;

int main( int argc, char ** argv ) {
    std::cout << "main()\n";
}
```